# apex always execute validation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Is it possible to execute validations on page load regardless if it is submitted or just loaded?

I need to implement it for ordinary validations created in processing page section and for min max validations assigned to number field.

Is it possible to implement?

Comment: Validations which are defined in the "On submit" branch? No. Can you explain your problem more?

Comment: @Tom, I have two date pickers which define date range. `From` date should not be later that 'to' date. There is a validation on page defined in `Page Processing`. With wrong dates validation is applied when page is submitted with button, but when page is reloaded after submission validation is not applied and date pickers contain wrong dates ('from' is later than 'to' date).

Comment: Would it be a solution to restrict the datepickers, through javascript? Of course, you should still always have a serverside validation to be on the safe side. It also sounds like you have no serverside validation in place yet - or do I get this wrong?

Comment: @Tom, I have a problem with server validation. I have a validation that works only when page is submitted. There is a button with action `Submit Page`, when it is used then validation is successfully applied and if there is an error in date pickers it will show a message. However if I reload page with an error message validation is not applied, and I get a page with wrong data (state of data pickers is saved in session) without any error message. So I need somehow apply validation every time page is loaded not only when it is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed: having a server side validation will throw an error, but the page has submitted and thus the changed values are in session state. You could try to prevent this by having a plsql validation which would blank out the session state value when an error occurs, but might not be optimal. I think that some javascript could alliviate some of the trouble.

Here is some javascript that restricts the selectable ranges in the to and from datepickers. It won't allow a user to pick a larger from than to date, and vice versa. It also sets the item to readonly, so that the user has to select through the datepicker and can not alter it by hand.

Page > Javascript > Function and Global Variable Declaration

```
function f_check_date(){
  var lFrom = $("#P6_DATE_FROM").datepicker("getDate"),
      lTo = $("#P6_DATE_TO").datepicker("getDate");

  if(lFrom > lTo || lTo < lFrom){
    //in case it does happen
    $("#P6_DATE_FROM").val('');
    $("#P6_DATE_FROM").val('');
    alert('Please select a valid date range.');
  } else {
    //when a date changes, the other datepicker has to be altered so the
    //range is adjusted
    $("#P6_DATE_FROM").datepicker("option","maxDate",lTo);
    $("#P6_DATE_TO").datepicker("option","minDate",lFrom);
  };
};
```

Dynamic Action, Page Load, Execute javascript

```
//on load, set the datepicker range in case a date is already present
//when the date changes, call the datecheck function
//and set item to readonly
$("#P6_DATE_FROM")
.datepicker("option","maxDate",$("#P6_DATE_TO").datepicker("getDate"))
.change(f_check_date)
.prop("readonly",true);
$("#P6_DATE_TO")
.datepicker("option","minDate",$("#P6_DATE_FROM").datepicker("getDate"))
.change(f_check_date)
.prop("readonly",true);
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that seems like a weak workaround. And using javascript will require duplication of validation code. What I would like is to either execute validations on page load or reset item to its default value in case validation fails.

Comment: I disagree and agree. Is this a workaround? In sense, yes. Does it improve user experience? In my opinion it does. The UI responds to what the user is doing, and these fields do have interactivity with eachother. It also prevents the user from entering a wrong range of dates, which alleviates much of the problem in my opinion. Combine it with a server-side validation, which can be a real validation and no process, and it's powerful. Should a wrong range still enter then it should be obvious to the user about what to do. If you have reports depending on the dates, you could alter their sql.

Comment: To further elaborate I want to point out that the code is very very portable. This is just javascript. You could create a function with 2 input parameters (from and to date field ids) and put this in a file. With one call it could do all the above. You could make this a dynamic action plugin even. You could after all argue that everything in apex is hard to use because even a simple validation would need to copied over for similar fields and creates duplication.